IntelliJ showing errors in standalone components
I recently created a new Angular 18 project, and I decided to use the standalone component approach. However, in my IntelliJ IDEA editor, I keep encountering the following error underlined in AppComponent.ts
AppComponent is not declared in any Angular module.
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'test';
}

The application works fine when I run it using ng serve. However, the IntelliJ IDEA editor keeps showing the error:
AppComponent is not declared in any Angular module.
What I’ve Tried:

Restarting IntelliJ and the TypeScript service.
Invalidating caches in IntelliJ.

My Question:
Is this error expected when using standalone components in Angular 17/18? If so, how can I resolve it, or is this simply a bug or misconfiguration in IntelliJ IDEA? Do I need to configure anything extra for Angular’s standalone components in IntelliJ?

Which version of IntelliJ do you use? I am using the latest WebStorm and don't have any issues with my standalone components.

i am using the 2021.2.4 version

You need to update your IntelliJ version, 2021.2.4 is really old. Angular standalone is a feature which was added in 2022. IDEs from 2021 have no chance of knowing about this feature and handling it properly.

ALright thanks mate! i will update to the newest version and lets see :)

Haha its fixed xD. Thanks for your fast repspond mate! Just update intelij and it works :)
